# How to know the current user in Angular

Tags: angular, windows, authentication

In Angular, is there a way to know the current user's login name? The user may login from Windows, and presumably Linux. The former is good enough though.
This is an intranet application, so I am worry about authentication issue, just the user name. Is there a simple and clean way?